# Wifi Notification in Wingpanel doesn't correspond with real status

Tags: wifi

[image]

In Wingpanel it seems that I have no or low wifi-connection. But my connection works fine. If I click on the wifi-icon and the list opens up, than all the curved lines of my connection are highlighted. But when I look at the icon alone, no line is highlighted. How can I fix this? (I am new at Linux and Loki.)

Answer (score 0):

I understand I am answering this late but this may be helpful for others at some point of time.

try reinstalling `libappindicator` and then logout and log back in.

Use the following command to reinstall `libappindicator`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libappindicator3-1 libappindicator1
```